# Android NDK C++ camera2 API: ACameraManager_getCameraIdList return 0 cameras

Tags: android, api, android-ndk, android-camera2

I'm trying to create C++ Android native camera wrapper using the NDK camera2 API (from abi level 24). I created some snippet code using an example I found and compile it for target API level 24 and run it on Android 7.1 phone:

```
ACameraManager *cameraManager = ACameraManager_create();
VB(cameraManager!=nullptr, "Could not create CameraManager.");
camera_status = ACameraManager_getCameraIdList(cameraManager, &m_camera_id_list);

if (camera_status != ACAMERA_OK) {

    LOGE("Failed to get camera id list (reason: %d)\n", camera_status);
    return ERR_CAMERAAPI_UNKNOWN_ERROR;
}

if (m_camera_id_list->numCameras < 1) {
    LOGE("No camera device detected.\n");
    return ERR_CAMERAAPI_UNKNOWN_ERROR;
}
```

When I run this naive code on Xiaomi mi4c Android 7.1 phone I get an empty camera list.

I also tried to run on the same phone a snippet created with Java camera2 API that does the same thing:

```
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice; 
Activity activity = getActivity();
CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

String[] cameraIds = manager.getCameraIdList()
manager.openCamera(cameraIds[0], mStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
```

This time I see in the logical that it actually finds two cameras and print their resolutions.

My manifest of course contains these lines:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="24" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

And I approve the permissions requests.

Does anyone knows why it finds the phone cameras when using the Java camera2 API but does not find them when using the NDK camera2 API?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem ? I have the same behavior with a Moto E4+ running Nougat 7.1.1. Have you tried calling the legacy API ?

Answer (score 3):

The NDK camera2 support does not work if

```
CameraCharacteristics.get(INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL) == INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LEGACY
```

This is probably the case of Xiaomi mi4c.

Comment: Thank you Alex, but if the Java camera2 API is just a JNI wrapper on top of the NDK camera2, so how come it does work on the same phone?

Comment: Is there another way to interface the phone camera in C++ in case of INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LEGACY is the supported hw level?

Comment: No, camera2 API is not a JNI wrapper around the NDK camera2. Notice that the C support for camera2 appeared much later, and only works on Nougat+. I have built a POC backport of this to Lollipop, but I never had a reason to roll this code to production. Especially this concerns the legacy level. In this case, camera2 is emulated fully in Java which calls the traditional Camera API. You can download this Java code from AOSP.

Comment: @AlexCohn Are you sure about this "only works on Nougat+" ?, because i have this issue in oreo(android version 8.1.0). For this android version, hardware level is two.

Comment: @BhunnuBaba: This is probably some different problem. If your OS is above API 24 and HARDWARE_LEVEL ≥ 2, but NDK camera API does not list the device, it may be a bug of your specific device (bugs happen even on API 29).